# Connect Rails application using Faraday to Java web service over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, oauth-2.0, faraday

First I will state what I am trying to do: I have a self-signed cert for development/test purposes being used by a Clojure/Jetty API that a Rails app needs to make requests to.  I have no difficulty connecting to it in Clojure using clj-http, which wraps Apache HttpClient, and can pass settings for keystore, key-password, truststore, and trust-password.  What I am *trying* to do is make ssl requests from a locally running Rails app to this secure API, whatever a good way to do that is.

Having explained what I am trying to do, it seems to me that the most straightforward way to accomplish this would be to plug in settings like these into Faraday (by the way I need to use faraday because that is the lib that the oauth2 lib uses to make http requests), but unsurprisingly, this Ruby library does not support something that is decidely part of the JVM ecosystem (and this is not a JRuby stack). Its configuration settings include client_cert, client_key, ca_file, ca_path, and cert_store.

Any ideas/ suggestions much appreciated!